# Microbot Alpha: how far does it consider others Microbots?

Tags: smash-up

Microbot Alpha says "All of your minions are considered Microbots."

Does this mean while this card is in play, every single minion in play and in discard and in my hand are considered Microbots?

- For every Microbot Fixer in play, does every single minion I have in play now get +1 because they are all microbots?
- If Microbot Archive is in play, does every single minion I have now cause me to draw a card when destroyed?
- If I play Microbot Reclaimer, can I shuffle any minions from my discard pile into my deck (by considering them *all* microbots)?

It looks like this link addresses the first item above: [Smash Up: Microbot Fixer + Microbot Alpha](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/smash-up-microbot-fixer-microbot-alpha?rq=1)

And it looks like this link addresses the 3rd item, implying that minions in the discard are not minions because they are out of play:
[Do actions that affect all cards also affect cards in your hand.?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12778/do-actions-that-affect-all-cards-also-affect-cards-in-your-hand?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, if the card says all your minions are microbots, then all your minions are microbots

Comment: See also: [Questions on Microbot Alpha](https://smashup.fandom.com/wiki/Robots#Questions_on_Microbot_Alpha).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. All minions are considered Microbots. So everything that applies to Microbots applies to all your minions in play.

However, as included in the Pretty Pretty Smash Up rules, page 10:

> "A minion" or "minions" means any minions in play unless stated
>   otherwise.

So minions in your discard pile are NOT affected.

See also [this discussion](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/847663/microbots) on Boardgamegeek.

Comment: Interesting link that sounds like it throws a wrench in possibly multiple cards, for instance the reference to the war raptor and questioning whether it no longer is a war raptor but now a microbot.

Comment: The fun part is that there is a whole section in the manual about conflicting rules.